# fully customize django admin site

Tags: python, django, user-interface

I am new to django. Is there any way to fully change django admin site UI? I have searched a lot but none of them works (most of them were so old like for 5 6 years ago).

The most common answer was to create an admin directory in template folders, then inside it a directory with app name and then model name. But nothing happened doing that.

Is it ever possible to have my fully customized UI? What should I do?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

List of great admin UI apps - https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-interface/